# The Tensorflow model graph built with keras.utils.plot_model does not show concatenations

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, densenet

I'm trying to build a dense block, so I wrote a simple example like this:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3))

layer1 = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(input_layer)
layer2 = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(layer1)
layer3 = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(layer2)
layer4 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(layer3)

concatenate([layer3, layer2])

concatenate([layer4, layer3])
concatenate([layer4, layer2])

model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=layer4, name="Dense_block")
keras.utils.plot_model(model, "info.png", show_shapes=True)
```

But the graph I got does not contain any concatenations:

[image]

May be something is wrong with my code?

Comment: concatenation is not part of your model

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Did you mean that my code is correct and that these concatenations just don't show up in the graph? Thanks!

Comment: Or do I need to somehow include them into the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layers 1 till 4 are connected and part of your model due to the call `model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=layer4, name="Dense_block")` with `outputs=layer4`. Your concatenate operations are not connected.

You could fix this by defining a new layer, for example `layer5 = concatenate([layer3, layer2])` and pass that layer to `outputs` in your model statement.

For the concatenating itself, I would advice you to use Keras' Concatenate layer: `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate`. [Reference here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/concatenate/)

```py
layer5 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([layer3, layer2])
model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=layer5, name="Dense_block")
```